# Initialization of Extended class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am getting object of a class AAA from somewhere and I want to add more information in that object. So, I am creating a new class BBB which is derived from AAA. The class BBB has additional field dictionary. I am populating this dictionary in derived class constructor which is taking the Class AAA object and array of item which I want to use as keys of dictionary and values of this dictionary are elements of a field of object of class AAA. I tried to create similar scenario in blow example code:

```
void Main(){    
     A obj = new A () ;
     obj.prop1 =  new int [] {5 ,10, 15}   ;
     obj.prop2 =  "Hello" ;
     obj.prop3 = "World" ;
//   obj.Dump () ;
     B obj2 = new B (new int [] {1,2,3}, obj)  ;     
//   obj2.Dump () ;

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class A {
    public int [] prop1 ;
    public string prop2 ;
    public string prop3 ;
}

public class B : A {
    public Dictionary <int, int> prop4 ;
    public B (int [] keys, A a) {
    prop4 = new Dictionary <int, int> () ;
        if (keys.Length == a.prop1.Length ) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < keys.Length ; i++ ) {
                prop4.Add (keys[i], a.prop1[i]) ;
            }
            // is there a way to obsolete below lines of code???
            this.prop1 = a.prop1 ; 
            this.prop2 = a.prop2 ;
            this.prop3 = a.prop3 ;
        }
        else {
            throw new Exception ("something wrong") ;
        }           
    }
}
```

In derived class constructor, I am filling the properties manually and I do not want to do it. Is there another way to do it. I have more than 20 properties in my actual class.

Comment: Seems more like you want an indexer instead? It looks like you want to access values from the integer array by key - can you explain the use case? Once you've done this once, you've done it - are you planning on doing this a million times with other objects?

Comment: The names `prop1`, `prop2`, `prop3`, and `prop4` are decisively poor.  They don't represent the same types and aren't used in the same way.  Thus it would be very helpful if you gave them names that more clearly indicated their use.

Comment: I want to add keys not indexer.

Comment: Keys and an indexer are the same thing in some ways - you are adding a dictionary which is just an indexer over a collection (ok it does more than just this but syntactically similar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't do what you're asking but I'd suggest creating a copy constructor for class `A` and using it with your class `B` constructor:

```
// Define other methods and classes here
public class A
{
    public int[] prop1;
    public string prop2;
    public string prop3;

    public A()
    {
    }

    public A(A orig)
    {
        prop1 = orig.prop1;
        prop2 = orig.prop2;
        prop3 = orig.prop3;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public Dictionary<int, int> prop4;

    public B(int[] keys, A a) : base( a )
    {
        prop4 = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        if (keys.Length == prop1.Length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
            {
                prop4.Add(keys[i], prop1[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("something wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Clean implementation with no side effects. Lovely.

Comment: I appreciate your efforts, however I do not want to modify my base class implementation.

Comment: @User1551892 Do not want to, or can't? The easy modification is almost always preferable to hacking in a workaround! This particular workaround involves a new constructor and nothing more.

Comment: Somehow, I can not because things are heavily dependent on each other, The motivation behind extending class AAA is "I can not modify base class".

Comment: Is it forbidden or impossible to modify class `A`?  If it's only forbidden, you have a strong case for obtaining permission to add a copy constructor (which won't modify any functionality of the class itself)

Comment: Is there a way to make sure, I am assigning values to all fields in second base class constructor.

Comment: There is no compile-time check for that, no

Answer (score 0):

Instance of `B` (which you are constructing) and instance of `A` (which you are passing to constructor of `B`) are not related - they hold different data, they sit on different memory addresses. The only way to update properties/fields of `B` instance from values of passed `A` is copying.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmmmm... Its a bit unclear and confusing what you up to but take a look at this:

Maybe its not related to what you need but at least it might give you an idea.

This is how you can create a dictionary from all the properties of a type.

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> DictionaryFromType(object atype)
{
    if (atype == null) return new Dictionary<string, object>();
    Type t = atype.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
    Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prp in props)
    {
        object value = prp.GetValue(atype, new object[]{});
        dict.Add(prp.Name, value);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Might help you out. If not let me know to remove this question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are implementing here is very similar to a `copy constructor`. Doing it by hand is the only way I'm afraid!

My advice is to use `Properties` in your class A definition and override the properties for your class B implementation:

```
// Define other methods and classes here
public class A
{
    public virtual int[] prop1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string prop2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string prop3 { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public Dictionary<int, int> prop4;

    public override int[] prop1
    {
        get
        {
            return m_WrappedAInstance.prop1;
        }
        set
        {
            m_WrappedAInstance.prop1 = value;
        }
    }

    public override string prop2
    {
        get
        {
            return m_WrappedAInstance.prop2;
        }
        set
        {
            m_WrappedAInstance.prop2 = value;
        }
    }

    public override string prop3
    {
        get
        {
            return m_WrappedAInstance.prop3;
        }
        set
        {
            m_WrappedAInstance.prop3 = value;
        }
    }

    A m_WrappedAInstance = null;
    public B(int[] keys, A a)
    {
        m_WrappedAInstance = a;
        prop4 = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        if (keys.Length == a.prop1.Length)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
            {
                prop4.Add(keys[i], a.prop1[i]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("something wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

Functionally, this will act similarly. The only downside is that your wrapped class A instance can no longer be changed independently of your class B instance. Is this a requirement?

Comment: Something to watch out for is deep vs shallow copying too - I mean do you want references to point to the same instances or not? It can be a nightmare depending on the class needing to be copied - just thought I'd pitch in

Comment: @Charleh A worthy consideration - it is why i always advocate doing it by hand when you can. Once you get into 'automatic deep copying', codebases get complicated. I usually serialise to do a deep copy :D

Comment: Aye, but that depends on stuff being serializable - I don't think I've ever really *needed* to write a copy constructor, not in .NET anyway... there's almost always a better way to do something when it comes to stuff like this

Answer (score 0):

Define an array.  Then cast the items in the array to individual properties

In class A

```
public object[] properties;

public int[] prop1 {
  get { return (int[]) properties[0]; }
  set { properties[0] = value; } }

public string prop2 {
  get { return (string)properties[1];  }
  set { properties[1] = value ; } }
```

Constructor of B

```
public B (int[] keys, A obj)
    {
        properties = A.properties;
    }
```